# How to disable Downloading of files from Google Drive from the API?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

A feature we would like to implement for a service within my company is the creation of Docs directly to Google Drive from our application (which is a web-app that already uses Google APIs), with the option of disabling the "Download as ...", "Publish to the web" and "Email as attachment" of the created files.

I know disabling download used to be available from the UI a while back and I was wondering if this option is available from the remote API (and possibly in the Java client as well).

At the end of the day we want the files created by our service to be editable online in the Google docs client (We are talking simple spreadsheets and word docs) but we do not want our employees to download them to their personal machines.

Thanks for any help and advice.